# After migrating to React Router Dom v6, am I using the Link component incorrectly?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I've just migrated my app from React Router Dom v5 to v6.

I've noticed an oddity.

My app is structured so that users moving between projects and sub-projects stay on the same URL (example.com/projects). The state is updated to change the project while keeping the URL the same.

So, for example, a user might go from projectA to projectB to projectC, all staying on the same route of /projects.

Prior to v6, the Link component handled this perfectly, including handling the browser's back button correctly.

But in v6 it appears that the Link component is, effectively, conflating the different states. If a user starts at /home, clicks projectA, then projectB, then the back button they will go back to /home rather than projectA.

This breaks my app.

Fortunately, I did a test and using useNavigate() behaves as expected (edit: almost. It seems to behave for now in my app, but the sandbox shows it doesn't work 100%).

In the short-term I've replaced the Link components with useNavigate via onClick events. But I'd rather use Link components.

Have I done something wrong? Or is this a bug with Links?

Code (FWIW):

```
state: { project: model.id } 

<Link to={pathname} state={state}>
   {children}
</Link>
```

Edit:

As suggested, I've created 3 Sandboxes.

For each Sandbox:

- On the home page, navigate to 'Project A'
- From the projects page, click 'Go to A'/'Go to B' a couple of times
- Click the browser back button until it stops doing anything

Expected

- The browser 'rewinds' the clicks, taking you back through the projects, eventually returning to the home page

What actually happens

- Sandbox 1 works
- Sandbox 2 only goes back once and then won't go any further
- Sandbox 3 will 'rewind' through the projects, but won't step back to the home page

CodeSandbox 1 (React 16/Router 5.2/using Links)
[Sandbox 1](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/confident-dew-v9vlr8)

CodeSandbox 2 (React 18/Router 6.22.3/using Links) [Sandbox 2](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/festive-bird-gvr896)

CodeSandbox 3 (React 18/Router 6.22.3/using useNavigate() instead of Links) [Sandbox 3](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/festive-bird-forked-x7mvnd)

Comment: have you checked migration guide? https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5

Comment: No, that's how you would use the `Link` component. We may need quite a bit more context here. Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the code you are working with? If possible could you create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of the code you are using that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: @DrewReese - I've added sandboxes to demonstrate. Hopefully it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit perplexing, and I can't say with any certainty *why* this is the case, but it seems that the links in your RRDv6 sandbox are "redirects" instead of normal pushes. Adding `replace={false}` to your links seems to produce the expected and desired behavior.

Note also that it is invalid to nest anchor tags within other anchor tags.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Route, Routes, Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/projects" element={<Project />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const Home = () => {
  const linkData = { pathname: "/projects", state: { project: "A" } };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home</h1>

      <Link to={linkData.pathname} state={linkData.state} replace={false}>
        Project A
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
const Project = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const project = location.state?.project;

  const linkToA = { pathname: "/projects", state: { project: "A" } };
  const linkToB = { pathname: "/projects", state: { project: "B" } };

  const linkToUse = project === "A" ? linkToB : linkToA;

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Project</h1>

      <h2>The project is {project}</h2>

      <Link to={linkToUse.pathname} state={linkToUse.state} replace={false}>
        Go to {project === "A" ? "B" : "A"}
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```